# Giant Reign 2 2017 GXP pressfit BB

Tags: bottom-bracket, compatibility, groupsets

I am currently running a 10 speed groupset on a Giant Reign 2 2017 and I am looking to upgrade to a 12 speed DUB groupset.  I'm wondering if this is possible with my current bottom bracket or what bottom bracket I would need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Giant uses Shimano's press fit BB standard - BB86 for road bikes, BB92 for MTBs. All you will need is a BB92 press fit BB for DUB spindles (some manufacturers may make BBs for 30mm spindles with a shim). For example, SRAM themselves make one such BB. Some manufacturers skip this combination, but there are a number of 3rd party manufacturers who offer it.

I have no direct experience, but I believe that some people are wary of using 29mm or 30mm spindle cranks in BB86 shells. Remember that Shimano has always stuck to a 24mm spindle, and they designed the shell without consideration of larger spindles. While you can buy a DUB or 30mm BB for that shell, there is less space for the bearings than if you used a 24mm spindle. Where space is constrained, a manufacturer can make the bearings smaller, but this decreases the amount of load the bearing can take and thus it may decrease bearing life. I'm not sure if there's a big penalty in real life.